# .NET Core display database change notification using signalR not working

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, signalr, service-broker

By following [display database change notification using signalR](https://www.freecodespot.com/blog/display-database-change-notification-using-signalr/)

Everything works well in updating the UI in realtime, but then shows an error on every DML in the database like:

```
UPDATE Jobs 
SET [Status] = 1,
    [Result] = '' 
WHERE [CertificateId] = 4108890
```

> Msg 592, Level 16, State 1, Procedure tr_dbo_Jobs_78e1a4fd-604c-464f-87ec-341a981ede5c_Sender, Line 44 [Batch Start Line 3]
> Cannot find object ID 1637580872 in database ID 8

After investigation, I found it creates a stored procedure

```
[dbo].[dbo_Jobs_78e1a4fd-604c-464f-87ec-341a981ede5c_QueueActivationSender]
```

Note: there is no reference to 1637580872 in the stored procedure created

Comment: Make sure you run the DML in the correct DB, one more thing, please check why `Procedure`  for `tr_dbo_Jobs` will excute. From the sample project repo,I can't find more details.

Comment: By the way the `SqlTableDenpendcy` belongs to 3rd library, will not get official support. And I think this post could also useful to you if you [want to use `SqlDenpendcy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1159844/implementing-signalr-in-asp-net-core-web-app-(mvc)).